# Heroku how many listeners can you have running simultaneously on one dyno?

Tags: node.js, heroku

Heroku redirected me to stackoverflow to ask my question here, so here we go:

**How many listeners can you have running simultaneously on one dyno?**

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "listeners"? Are you talking about multiple threads controlled by a master process using a single port? Listening on multiple ports? Something else?

Comment: How many threads a master thread (a dyno) is capable of listening too at once.

Comment: As far as I know there's no public documentation about the number of cores a dyno can use, or anything like that. I've definitely run 4+ [Gunicorn workers](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/design.html#how-many-workers) on a Dyno before without any issues, but that doesn't really map to threads. I suggest trying it out and seeing how it works. At the _very_ least, please provide the code you're talking about in your question.

Comment: @chris I haven't coded anything yet, I just need to know it in order to know how I need to structure my application. If there is a limit I will have to code it differently that if there otherwise weren't one. How would you suggest trying it out? I don't think it's unlimited - else I am going overload their server - but I believe it's pretty high by what you are stating.

Comment: "How would you suggest trying it out?" By writing a minimal prototype, something like a [mcve], and deploying it to Heroku. See if it behaves how you want it to. In some circles this would be called a "[spike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spike_(software_development))".

Comment: @Chris around 7-10 and I start to get issues on a heroku server which works just fine on localhost. By the way I have asked the question to heroku support and is awaiting an answer which might be a little clearer.